# OWIN/Identity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a class library with a SignIn method with a lot of logic in order for a member to sign in. The problem that I am facing is that I add a claim of "Fullname" to the identity and it works fine, but as soon as the user log's off and logs in again the claim is gone.

If I inspect the users identity the claim is available on the second log in until the RedirectToAction method is hit, then all the custom claims are no longer in the users identity. This includes the Fullname and Role claims.

---

```
var roles = _dbsme.sp_GetAllRoles(user.Id);
ClaimsIdentity identity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties1 = new AuthenticationProperties();
authenticationProperties1.IsPersistent = false;
AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties2 = authenticationProperties1;
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", user.Firstname + " " + user.Surname));
foreach (string role in roles)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
}

AuthenticationManager.SignIn(authenticationProperties2, identity);
signInStatus = SignInStatus.Success;
```

Comment: Are you checking the identity on the next request? i.e. not the current request that sets up the identity and logs them in?

Comment: @Shoe, how would you check the identity on the next request? What I find strange is that works perfectly first sign in, but if the user logs off and then on again that the claims are removed on the RedirectToAction (in the account controller). I do not redirect from the class library.

Comment: `User.Identity` gets the current identity of the user. After you redirect you can check the claims object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be adding claims via the `UserManager` in order to have them persisted (if you use ASP.NET Identity 2 with EF).

```
userManager.AddClaim(userId, new Claim(claimType,claimValue));
```

Please note that if you add the claims on a user that is currently logged-in you need to sign that user in again (to put the new information in the cookie).

Comment: I changed my "identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));" to "_userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));" and the process is working 100% now. Thank you @pysco68.
After looking more deeply I picked up that identity.AddClaim uses mscorlib and usermanager uses Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core and the claimstore. In short....DO NOT use identity directly in ASP.Net Identity 2.

Comment: @Inox You can use claims "directly". In fact if you look at the classes that are referenced in the `UserManager` you will see they point to `mscorlib`.

Comment: @Shoe, that is what I did as well, but the claims are not set properly in the claim store due to some unknown reason. But the user manager add claim method obviously does do it correctly. When I use it directly, then I get weird behavior when logging on, off and on again within the same session with the same user.